# Aggregating data in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to explore Pandas library and stopped by an example that I frequently face and I think pandas had the solution for it. Given the folloing code:

```
In [63]: d1 = np.random.rand(3,3)
In [63]: d2 = np.random.rand(3,3)

In [64]:s1 = pandas.Series(d1,index = [['a1']*d1.shape[0],
                             [4]*d1.shape[0],
                             range(d1.shape[0])])

Out[64]:a1  4  0    [ 0.00881133  0.71344668  0.03611378]
               1    [ 0.37328776  0.63195947  0.23000941]
               2    [ 0.68466443  0.85891677  0.31740809]

In [65]: s2 = pandas.Series(d2,index = [['a2']*d2.shape[0],
                             [5]*d2.shape[0],
                             range(d2.shape[0])])
Out[65]:a2  5  0    [ 0.00881133  0.71344668  0.03611378]
               1    [ 0.37328776  0.63195947  0.23000941]
               2    [ 0.68466443  0.85891677  0.31740809]

s = s1.append(s2)

a1  4  0    [ 0.00881133  0.71344668  0.03611378]
       1    [ 0.37328776  0.63195947  0.23000941]
       2    [ 0.68466443  0.85891677  0.31740809]
    5  0    [ 0.00881133  0.71344668  0.03611378]
       1    [ 0.37328776  0.63195947  0.23000941]
       2    [ 0.68466443  0.85891677  0.31740809]
```

How to obtain a list of all the data matrices alone without their labels?

Answer (score 2):

`s.values` will do the trick.

From the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html?highlight=values#pandas.DataFrame.values): `DataFrame.values` Convert the frame to its Numpy-array matrix representation."

I think you mean `pandas.DataFrame` above (not `Series`). `Series.values` exists as well.

Comment: I meant `pandas.Series`. If you look at JustInTime's code, he has created `pandas.Series`, not `pandas.DataFrame`s.

Comment: Passing a 2-dimensional array to Series won't result in very favorable behavior; the OP should use a DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting errors running your code. However, to convert a pandas Series to a numpy array, use the [`pandas.Series.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html#pandas.Series.values)  method. Wes's [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) is very well done. Spend some time reviewing...